# Update charts values every 30 seconds from springboot backend to angular4 frontend

Tags: ajax, angular, spring-boot, charts, updates

I'm working on a project where I have  a dashboard with lots of charts and variables that needs to be updated every 30 seconds. I'm going to use Springboot to create an API that will return  JSON values, and I'm going to fetch the values with Angular4 and render my graphs. As I'm no expert neither in Angular or Springboot I need your advice on how can I approach this issue, and what will be the easiest way to dynamically  update my charts . Do I need to use AJAX? 
Are there any other easy ways of doing this?
Thanks you all in anticipation.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've already tried.

Comment: I'm still working on the diagrams and flowchart trying to have a more complete idea of how my app will work .My question is just a call for some suggestions , or some ideas on how this can be accomplished.  I don't need code examples just a way of how to integrate  this technologies .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use HttpClientModule, for your requests to the Springboot API. And the timer functionality is pretty simple:

```
export class DataService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  getData() {
    interval(30*1000)//just instead of writing 30000
           .pipe(switchMap(() => this.http.get('your url')))
           .subscribe(data => do things with data);
  }
}
```

This is one way to go, you can also use [timer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html) for example. Replace `interval` with `timer(0, 30*1000)` where 0 how much time to wait until the first try, and the second value is how often to repeat it. Here you can read about [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) and [interval](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html).

Bare in mind, that I've written it using RxJS 5+ with pipe, and Angular 5+ using HttpClient, the way might differ in older versions, and I highly recommend using the latest versions.

Comment: Okeei, this clarifies things a lot for me! thank you very much! I will going to do a simple  example case and try it.

Comment: Go ahead. Do it on https://stackblitz.com/ so that I can take a look if you have any troubles.

Comment: I've managed to create my request Class , with lots of effort to be honest, I've had a hard time writting the JSON Object.( I've been using Angular for like 2 days). Here is the link of my class https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ba8hw1 .If you have some tips to improve it I'm happy to accept some

Comment: Yees! works pretty well! Thank you a lot for the help , it was way easier than I thought . P.S it doesn't work on stackblitz as the server I used is private but on my Computer works wonderfull

Comment: I've looked at the stackblitz example, it looks good, but I hope that in the app you will move the API call to a service and all the code related to it also. Read the style guide, it will help you structure the app properly.

Comment: If you're happy with my answer, please consider to mark it as answered.